# How to concatenate partially sequential occurring rows in data frame using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a csv as follows. which is broken into multiple rows.

like as follows

```
Names,text,conv_id
tim,hi,1234
jon,hello,1234
jon,how,1234
jon,are you,1234
tim,hey,1234
tim,i am good,1234
pam, me too,1234
jon,great,1234
jon,hows life,1234
```

So i want to concatenate the sequentially occuring elements into one row
as follows and make it more meaningful

Expected output:

```
Names,text,conv_id
tim,hi,1234
jon,hello how are you,1234
tim,hey i am good,1234
pam, me too,1234
jon,great hows life,1234
```

I tried a couple of things but I failed and couldn't do can anyone please guide me how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) + [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) 
to be able to create the appropriate groups through [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and then use `join` applied to each group using [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html).`'conv_id'`, an `'Names'` are added to the groups so that they can be retrieved using [`Series.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html). Finally, [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) is used to place the columns in the initial order

```
groups=df['Names'].rename('groups').ne(df['Names'].shift()).cumsum()
new_df=( df.groupby([groups,'conv_id','Names'])['text']
        .apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))
        .reset_index(level=['Names','conv_id'])
        .reindex(columns=df.columns) )

print(new_df)
```

---

```
  Names               text  conv_id
1   tim                 hi     1234
2   jon  hello,how,are you     1234
3   tim      hey,i am good     1234
4   pam             me too     1234
5   jon    great,hows life     1234
```

**Detail:**

```
print(groups)

0    1
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    3
6    4
7    5
8    5
dtype: int64
```